# Instagram Authentication and redirect_uri to my app

Tags: swift, oauth, xcode6, instagram

I have a problem with Instagram authentication. I use OAuthSwift to authorize my app. After the user accept my app I want to redirect again to the app, How can I do that with the redirect_uri? And is it possible open the Instagram app or is it only possible to authenticate with the browser?